# Using L'Hospital's rule to prove $f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x-h)}{2h}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$
f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x-h)}{2h}. $$ It is given that the derivative of $f$ at $x$ exists.

If I use L'Hospital's rule and differentiate top and bottom wrt $h$, I get

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f'(x+h) + f'(x-h)} {2}$$

Then what? I am really lost on this one. I can get the result without using the rule, but the challenge is to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: The stated equality can be proved, without extra assumptions, working with the definition of differentiability. In order to solve it using per se L'Hopitals one must make the extra (stronger) assumption that f' is continuous at x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is (implicitly) assuming that the derivative of $f$ is continuous at $x$. Note that you forgot the inner derivative of the second term in the numerator, so that the limit you got is not correct. The correct limit you get is $\lim_{h\to 0} (f'(x+h)+f'(x-h))/2$ which, by continuity of $f'$ at $x$, evaluates to $(f'(x)+f'(x))/2=f'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. But what I fail to see is how, and I would be really grateful if you can kindly take your time to explain this to me, $f'(x+h) + f'(x-h) = 2f'(x)$. More specifically, why is it that $f'(x+h) = f'(x)$ or $f'(x-h)= f'(x)$? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Or is it that we are taking the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ which is why we are getting $f'(x+h) = f'(x)$? How does the continuity of $f'$ come into play here?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I think the question doesn't assume that. If one tries to use L'H to solve it, one needs that extra assumption, but the question can be solved without the extra assumption other ways...

Comment: none of the equalities you mention are true. What is true is that under the extra assumption of continuity of f' at x the limit of f'(x+h), as h goes to 0, is f'(x). Similarly for the limit of f'(x-h). Without the extra assumption of continuity of f' at x you can't use L'Hopitals to prove the result (though the result remains true).

Comment: @ N.S. I don't know exactly how the original question is formulated. If it requires to use L'Hopitals then it must make the extra assumption of continuity of f' at x, otherwise that approach won't work. Of course, this is a very strange question since, of course, the claim is true always.

Answer (score 7):

L'Hospital is the wrong approach since you only know that $f$ is differentiable at $x$, and you don't know that $f'$ is continuous. That is what you need for that approach.

Anyhow

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{1}{2} \left[  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}+ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x)- f(x-h)}{h}\right]$$

By the definition of differentiability at $x$ we have

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$$

and after the substitution $h=-t$ you get

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x)- f(x-h)}{h}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f(x)- f(x+t)}{-t}
=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f(x+t)- f(x)}{t} =f'(x)$$

thus

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{1}{2} [ f'(x)+f'(x)]=f'(x) \,.$$

**P.S.** If the problem asks you explicitly to use L'H, and you don't have the extra condition that $f$ is differentiable around $x$ and $f'$ is continuous at $x$, then the problem is wrong.

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$. Then by the Squeze Theorem you can prove that $f'(0)=0$.

But

$$f'(x)=2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$$

and hence

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f'(0+h)+ f'(0-h)}{2}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {2h \sin(\frac{1}{h})-\cos(\frac{1}{h})+2h \sin(\frac{1}{h})-\cos(\frac{1}{h})}{2}=\mbox{Does Not Exist}$$

Comment: OP explicitly indicated an interest in a proof using L'Hopitals.

Comment: The problem does indicate the derivability of $f$ at $x$; however, it does not state the extra assumption. Let me look into it again.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I saw but that is odd since any proof involving L'H needs extra assumptions, which are actually not needed...

Comment: @user43901 Without the extra assumption, use the counterexample I provided with $x=0$ ;)

Comment: I completely agree with you guys! Another question, how can one go about visualizing this process? Can there be a picture one can draw to substantiate the proof IF the extra assumption is given?

Comment: @user43901 Intuitively if the function is "nice" , then picking points $PQ$ on the graph of $f$ equally distant to the left and right of $x$, the slope of $PQ$  when the two points approach $(x,f(x))$ goes to the slope of the tangent....

Comment: Okay, why equidistant? When you say the points approach $(x,f(x))$, do you mean that the points are shrinking to become one point; hence, the tangent?

Comment: Yes, and equidistant because $f(x+h)-f(x-h)/2h$ is the slope of the lien through $P(x+h,f(x+h))$ and $Q(x-h, f(x-h))$.

Comment: Ah, the rise over the run. Man, sometimes the simplest things catch you off-guard!

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)- f(x-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f'(x+h) + f'(x-h)} {2} = \frac{2f'(x)}{2}=f'(x)$$

though it's a bit circular.

Your mistake was when you differentiated, you forgot to change the sign before $f'(x-h)$.

Comment: Why is $\lim_{h \to 0} f'(x+h)=f'(x)$? And why does $f'(x+h)$ even exist?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents $h$ from being zero like before (where a 0/0 results)\, and because of continuity, I can simply let $h=0$.

Comment: The problem only tells you that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. And the derivative of a function is not necessarily continuous.... Try taht with $f(x)=x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: @N.S. If it is not continuous there, then it is not differentiable there, no?

Comment: @Aragon Yes you are right if $f$ is differentiable then $f$ is continuous. BUT you are using that $f'$ is continuous, not that $f$ is. And that is not true...

Comment: @N.S. You are correct in asserting that, but I think I must make this assumption unless there is some way to avoid that!

Comment: Just to jump in, if we are told that $f$ is differentiable at $x$, that implies that $f$ is continuous, right? or does that also imply $f'$ is continuous at $x$? Just a little confused now.

Comment: @Aragon Well that is what the poster must probably clarify. One must make that extra assumption if one uses the L'H, but the problem follows immediately without any extra assumptions from the definition of the derivatives. The question is: was he asked to prove it with L'H, or did he thought about using L'H and failed.... I think it is the last, and our discussion probably emphasize why...

Comment: @user43901 Only $f$ is continuous. The function $x^2\sin(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ is differentiable everywhere, and $f$ is continuous at $0$ but $f'$ is NOT continuous at $0$.

Comment: No, the problem asks to be solved with L.H. I proved it without using it since as you said, it follows from the definition.